# Wagtail multi-site main site showing blog items from other sites

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail, multisite

I have created a Wagtail multi-site. Within it, I have a BlogOverviewPage where all Blog items are listed. The problem is that the "main site" also lists Blog items for other sites. I have been experimenting using different queries in get_context, but without any luck. The strange thing is that it is 1 way, the main site lists blog items for other sites, but not the other way around.

This is my code:

```
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super().get_context(request)
    context['blogpages'] = self.get_children().live().order_by('-go_live_at')
    return context
```

I also tried this:

```
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super().get_context(request)
    site = self.get_site()
    context['blogpages'] = BlogPage.objects.all().live().in_site(site).order_by('-go_live_at')
    return context
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it seems I was close. This did the trick:

```
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        site = Site.find_for_request(request)
        context['blogpages'] = self.get_children().all().live().in_site(site).order_by('-go_live_at')
        return context
```